# How to implement Transparent Data Encryption(TDE) in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Want to implement Transparent Data Encryption(TDE) in PostgreSQL? I got some steps to implement TDE on tablespace but the parameters like **keystore_location** and **tablespace_encryption_algorithm** don't exist in postgresql.conf, when I tried to add those parameters it gave an error.

link from where I got the steps:-
[https://arctype.com/blog/transparent-data-encryption/#:~:text=Transparent%20Data%20Encryption%2C%20or%20TDE,the%20first%20line%20of%20defense](https://arctype.com/blog/transparent-data-encryption/#:%7E:text=Transparent%20Data%20Encryption%2C%20or%20TDE,the%20first%20line%20of%20defense).

If this doesn't work then how to implement TDE with pgcrypto.

Comment: There is nothing built-in. The blog post you are quoting seems to refer to [Fujitsu Enterprise Postgres](https://www.postgresql.fastware.com/blog/securing-your-data-with-transparent-data-encryption) which is a commercial Postgres offering from Fujitsu. There is also [a fork](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/products/postgresql-transparent-data-encryption/) from Cybertec that provides TDE.